# How to make one extended <tr> in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table as you see in the picture:
[image]

What I am trying to do is extend the date row till the end. So, I want blue background for whole row.

Here is my code for this:

```
<table class="table">
            <tbody>
            <tr class="list-heading"><td>DATE</td></tr>
            <tr v-for="(r, index) in filteredRows.slice(pageStart, pageStart + countOfPage)" class="list-content">
<!--                <th>{{ (currPage-1) * countOfPage + index + 1 }}</th>-->
                <td>{{ r.time }}</td>
                <td>{{ r.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ r.name }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I am using vue, but I dont think it is related to this.
And here is my css:

```
table .list-heading {
    background-color: var(--main-title-color);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: On ```<td>DATE</td>``` use a colspan=3, more info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `colspan` attribute of `td` to achieve this:

```
<tr class="list-heading"><td colspan="3">DATE</td></tr>
```

`colspan` specifies the number of columns in a table that a cell should span (literally *column span*).

There's some information about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_td_colspan.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `td colspan` attribute. Something like this:

```
<tr class="list-heading"><td colspan="3">DATE</td></tr>
```

It should expand the td to occupy 3 columns, you may change the number of columns as needed.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">DATE</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following code snippet using `colspan`

```
<tr class="">
<td colspan="td-number">value</td>
</tr>
tr.list-content{
color: red;
background: blue;
}
```